# WPF - MVVM - ViewNavigation not working when cliking button in UserControl

Tags: mvvm

I am new to WPF MVVM. I have MainWindow.xaml here Grid is splited into two columns. Column1 hooked with MenuUserControl.xaml which has two button called Page1 and Page2. Column2 hooked with ContentControl which is used to display view based on button click in MenuUserControl.xaml.
View navigation not working when I click the button. Please give working solution.

I have ViewModel for MainWindowViewModel.cs and MenuuserControlViewModel.cs also Page1UserControlViewModel and Page2UserControlViewModel.
MainWindowViewModel contains property called SelectedViewModel which is binded with ContentControl

```
**MainWindowViewModel.cs**
public class MainWindowViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private BaseViewModel selectedViewModel;
        public BaseViewModel SelectedViewModel
        {
            get { return selectedViewModel; }
            set
            {
                selectedViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedViewModel");
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
            }
        }
     }

**MenuUserControlViewModel.cs**

public class MenuUserControlViewModel : MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ICommand Page1Command { get; set; }
        public ICommand Page2Command { get; set; }

        public MenuUserControlViewModel ()
        {
            Page1Command = new BaseCommand(OpenPage1);
            Page2Command = new BaseCommand(OpenPage2);
        }
        private void OpenPage1(object obj)
        {
            SelectedViewModel = new Page1UserControlViewModel ();
        }
        private void OpenPage2(object obj)
        {
            SelectedViewModel = new Page2UserControlViewModel ();
        }
    }
```

**MenuUserControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfNavigationViewTestApplication.Views. MenuUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfNavigationViewTestApplication.Views"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfNavigationViewTestApplication.ViewModel"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Height="460" Width="154">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="menuButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="130"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        </Style>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MenuUserControlViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="105"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="90" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Content="Page1" Command="{Binding Page1Command}"  />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}" Content="Page2" Command="{Binding Page2Command}"/>                    
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" />
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >                    
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical"  >            
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfNavigationViewTestApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"       
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfNavigationViewTestApplication.Views"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfNavigationViewTestApplication.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Master Part List" Width="1250" Height="700" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">


    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>


    <Window.Resources>


        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Page1ViewModel}">
            <local: Page1UserControlView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Page2ViewModel}">
            <local: Page2UserControlView/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="125" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GridSplitter  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" Background="Gray"  ShowsPreview="True" IsEnabled="False" />     

              <Grid Name="MenuGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="3,13,3,3">
                <local:MplMenuView DataContext="{Binding Path= MplMenuViewModel}" />
            </Grid> 

            <Grid Name="PageGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="13,13,3,3">               
                <ContentControl x:Name="Pages" Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
            </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoPuR.png)

Comment: Where is your View do you use a DataTemplate set it ?

Comment: Yes i am using Data Template in MainWindow.xaml. <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel: Page1UserControlViewModel }">
            <local: Page1UserControlView/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel: Page2UserControlViewModel }">
            <local: Page2UserControlView />
        </DataTemplate>        

    </Window.Resources>

Comment: You should add this to your Question and also add the xaml for your Buttons. Did you use a Breakpoint to see if your OnPageView gets fired?